# How to move two items at the same time in a QML ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I use QtQuick and I made a QML project able to drag&drop items.

I am trying to add a rule to the drag&drop feature: **You cannot drop your item between two specified items**.

*To explain my problem, items will be rectangles*.

For example:

*RULE:* **You are not allowed to move a rectangle between the rectangle 2 and the rectangle 3**.

In this case, I am trying to move rectangle 2 and 3 **at the same time** when I need to move one of them. But I can't succeed and only one is moved.

**Here is an example**:

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    width: 1000; height: 1000
    ListView {
        id: root
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height

        model: DelegateModel {

            id: visualModel
            model: myModel
            model: ListModel {
                id: colorModel
                ListElement { someData }
                ...

            }

            delegate: MouseArea {

                property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

                id: delegateRoot
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                width: root.width; height: 100
                drag.target: icon
                drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
                drag.minimumY: 0

                Rectangle {
                  blablaData

                }

//IMPORTANT PART

                DropArea {
                    anchors { fill: parent; margins: 15 }

                    onEntered: {
                        if(drag.source.visualIndex <delegateRoot.visualIndex ) { //Only when my item is going down, I didn't implement the "up move"
                            if(drag.source.visualIndex==2) {
                                visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex,2) //This is where I try to move two items at the same time, not working
                            }
                            else if(drag.source.visualIndex==3) {
                            //Do nothing, already moved when it was rectangle 2
                            }
                            else {
                               visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                            }
                        }
                    }
               }
          }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your wording."You are not allowed to move a rectangle between the rectangle 2 and the rectangle 3", yet you're trying to move 2 and 3? "I am trying to move rectangle 2 and 3 at the same time when I need to move one of them"? Which is it.....do you need yo move both or one of them?

Or essentially Rectangles 2 and 3 are locked together?

Comment: Hello, sorry if it was not clear. It means that they are locked together. If I try to move one, it will move both, and you cannot insert another rectangle between them.